# Adding a post-purchasing share following an order

Tags: share, facebook-apps

I'm attempting to add a 'Share your order with your friends' option to our retail based website, and am following the faq based here: https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=201527026558981

I have managed to manipulate the code as I think is correct, however in the FAQ answers the setup on the App is vague at best. 
When testing in dev (on localhost) I'm receiving the following error:

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

In the basic settings of the app I have no idea what settings need entering around the auth domain, site url, canvas url etc - I'm new to the facebook dev side of things. As far as I can tell I shouldnt need a site URL, as am not using facebook login. Does the canvas URL need to be populated, and if so, does that mean I then need to create a new page for the content of this app?

The code I'm running is:

```
    <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: '1111111111111', status: true, cookie: true,
    xfbml: true});
    };
    (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
    </script>

                          <script>
                            function stream_publish(publish_text) {
                            var publish = {
                            method: 'stream.publish',
                            message: publish_text,
                            attachment: {
                            name: 'xxxxxxxx',
                            description: (
                            'xxxxxxxxx' ),
                            href: 'http://www.mydomain.com',
                            media: [
                            {
                            type: 'image',
                            href: 'http://www.mydomain.com',
                            src: 'http://www.mdomain.com/image',
                            }
                            ]
                            },
                            action_links: [
                            { text: 'Buy Now', href: 'http://www.mydomain.com', }
                            ],
                            user_prompt_message: 'Tell your friends'
                            };
                            FB.ui(publish);
                            }
                          </script>
```

Can anyone advise how this should be done and what I'm missing?

Many thanks

Piers

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, you don't have mydomain.com setup in your app settings.